# Two-dimensional subespace suplementary of another one

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a real normed space. All subspaces $S$ of codimension $1$ (hyperplane) in $E$ is either, closed or dense. What do say about a similar property when $S$ is of codimension $2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

Let $S$ be a  linear subspace of the linear space  $E$ of codimension $2$. Take an arbitrary vector $x\in E\setminus S$. Let $S’=\langle \{x\}\cup S\rangle$ be a linear hull of the set $\{x\}\cup S$. Then $S$ is a subspace of codimension $1$ of the space $S’$ and $S’$ is a subspace of codimension $1$ of the space $E$. So if $S$ in closed in $S’$ and $S’$ is closed in $E$ then $S$ is closed in $E$ too. If $S$ in dense in $S’$ and $S’$ is dense in $E$ then $S$ is dense in $E$ too. In the rest of cases $S$ is neither closed, nor dense in $E$.

Comment: It seems the same reasoning works for S of codimension n (obviously the question goes for E of infinite dimension).Are there "concrete" examples of (the pertinence of) this?. Tanks, dear Alex.